# Convert Twitter Timestamp?

Tags: php

ive got the user created date timestamp using twitter API `"created_timestamp": "1437815864820"` but the timestamp is different from php time() format which is `1602426884`.

and when i convert the twitter timestamp to date using `date('m/d/Y', 1437815864820)` it shows `12/09/41628` when it supposed between `Agustus 2009` (my twitter created date).

ive searched around and unfortunately i cant find the solution for this, some says that it was 64bit format or something im not sure.

my goal is to check if the created timestamp is smaller than current timestamp, which mean that the user account was created before the specific timestamp

```php
if( $created_timestamp < time() ){
//continue
}
```

Comment: Did you look at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tools-and-libraries/using-postman?

Comment: it could be in milliseconds, try `php -r 'print  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",1437815864820/1000);'`, but this gives 2015, are you sure its 2009 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I assume that the Timestamps are in milliseconds. In that case you need to convert them into seconds to be able to parse them.

```php
echo date("m/d/Y", $created_timestamp / 1000);
```